# Real time data streaming with 1 writer and N concurrent readers

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, algorithm, concurrency

A server controls 1 writer continuously producing data frames in real time and N possible concurrent read requests. Whenever a reader makes a request to the server, the reader should be able to get the most recent produced frame or wait for it, if not available. Although, it is allowed for N different readers to concurrently "consume" the same frame, each individual reader must not read the same frame more than one time.

Is there any well-known algorithm or a strategy for the above problem which does not waste too many resources and gives the readers a good throughput?

For now my idea is to use the so called "triple buffering" (one buffer per frame), where two buffers are filled by the writer alternatively and one buffer is shared by the concurrent readers. If the number of concurrent readings is 0, once a frame has been produced, the corresponding buffer can be swapped with the buffer dedicated to the readers. It seems an easy model, although all the concurrent readers might be affected by the timings of the slowest reader in the group. The problem about making sure that one reader cannot get the same frame two times has still to be solved with some sort of synchronisation in a clean way which fits the above model.

If you any other idea, or code (in modern C++ is preferred), C++ library... I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the leader of project Disruptor: [Martin Thompson](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/) has this new project: [Aeron](https://github.com/real-logic/Aeron) and it's super fast. What's more, it's already support C++ api. Check out the introduction video and article from highscalability:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM4YskS94b0
http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/11/17/aeron-do-we-really-need-another-messaging-system.html

Comment: np :) this is pretty new though. I subscribe highscalability and that's how I know it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use disruptor pattern here. It uses ring buffers to effectivly pass data between threads. See [multicast events section here](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Introduction). The LMAX disruptor was originaly [written in java](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/), though some implementation exists for c++. See [pure c version](https://github.com/redjack/varon-t), [c++11 version](https://github.com/fsaintjacques/disruptor--) and [another c++ version](https://github.com/bytemaster/disruptor). Also, have you seen [intel thread building blocks library](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)? It has some usefull and highly effective concurrent data structures, scheduler, synchronization primitives for c++. Hope this helps...